# Separate specialized asynctask class for each job or a unified universal class accepting lots of parameters

Tags: java, android, oop, android-asynctask

My android app gets data from a server API with which it communicates by using several Async Task classes that I've created for each job I need.

Here are the names of the classes so far:

[image]

and here are two classes so you can see what Im talking about:

```
public class DeleteUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    int success;
    private Context context;
    private OnUserDeletionListener listener;
    private String userToBeDeleted;
    private JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_DELETION_SUCCESS = "Deletion Success";
    private static final String TAG_DELETION_FAILURE_ACCOUNT_NOT_DELETED = "Account Not Deleted";
    private static final String TAG_DELETION_FAILURE_CONNECTION_ERROR = "Connection Error";
    
    public DeleteUser(Context context, OnUserDeletionListener listener, String userToBeDeleted) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.userToBeDeleted = userToBeDeleted;
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        ShowLoadingMessage.loading(context);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        int success;

            try {
                List<NameValuePair> deleteUserAccount = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                deleteUserAccount.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", userToBeDeleted));

                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(Configurationz.URLs.PHP_DELETE_USER_ACCOUNT, "POST", deleteUserAccount);

                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    return "Deletion Success";
                } else if (success == 2) {
                    return "Account Not Deleted";

                } else {
                    return "Connection Error";
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Connection Error";
            }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        ShowLoadingMessage.dismissDialog();
        if(listener != null) {
            if (result.contentEquals(TAG_DELETION_SUCCESS)) {
                listener.onUserDeletionSuccess();
            } else if(result.contentEquals(TAG_DELETION_FAILURE_ACCOUNT_NOT_DELETED)) {
                listener.onUserDeletionFailure(result);
            } else if(result.contentEquals(TAG_DELETION_FAILURE_CONNECTION_ERROR)) {    
                listener.onUserDeletionFailure(result); 
            }
        }
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

and here is one more class:

```
public class GetCategoriesFromDatabase extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<String>> {
    int success;
    private Context context;
    private OnGetCategoriesFromDatabaseListener listener;
    private JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    private final static String TAG_GET_CATEGORIES = "get_categories";
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_FAILURE = "failure";
    private static final String TAG_CONNECTION_ERROR = "Connection Error";
    ArrayList<String> categoriesArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String reason;

    public GetCategoriesFromDatabase(Context context, OnGetCategoriesFromDatabaseListener listener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        ShowLoadingMessage.loading(context, "Loading Categories");
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... args) {
        int success;

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> getCategories = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            getCategories.add(new BasicNameValuePair("request", TAG_GET_CATEGORIES));

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(Configurationz.URLs.PHP_GET_CATEGORIES, "GET", getCategories);

            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {

                categoriesArray.add("All Categories");
                JSONArray categoriesListJSONArray = json.getJSONArray("data");
                if (categoriesListJSONArray != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < categoriesListJSONArray.length(); i++) {
                        categoriesArray.add(categoriesListJSONArray.get(i).toString());
                    }
                }
                return categoriesArray;

            } else if (success == 2) {
                reason = "failure";
                return null;
            } else {
                reason = "Connection error";
                return null;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            reason = "Connection error";
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> categoriesArray) {
        ShowLoadingMessage.dismissDialog();
        if (listener != null) {
            if (categoriesArray.size() > 1) {
                listener.onGetCategoriesFromDatabaseSuccess(categoriesArray);
            } else if (reason.contentEquals(TAG_FAILURE)) {
                listener.onGetCategoriesFromDatabaseFailure(reason);
            } else if (reason.contentEquals(TAG_CONNECTION_ERROR)) {
                listener.onGetCategoriesFromDatabaseFailure(reason);
            }

        }
        super.onPostExecute(categoriesArray);
    }
}
```

Some of the activities implement quite a few listeners, for example 2-3 of these:

[image]

So my question is:

is it better to have many similar asynctask classes that do specialized jobs or should I try to come up with a universal asynctask class that will accept lots of parameters and will be highly customized, and will replace all these classes? Which is the more "professional" approach? What do I do with listeners in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is find all the similar variables and put that in an abstract superclass. In your case, I see stuff like

```
int success;
private Context context;
private OnUserDeletionListener listener;
private JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_DELETION_FAILURE_CONNECTION_ERROR = "Connection Error";
```

If your preExecute and postExecute have similar code in it, do the same for them and provide abstract method for the specific stuff in each task. This should make everything much clearer and also make developing new tasks simpler.

I would definitely not put everything in one class because it would be extremely bloated and difficult to maintain.

The same advice holds for your listeners.

---

**EXAMPLE**

```
public abstract class MyAbstractTask<T> extends AsyncTask<String, String, T>{
    int success;
    protected Context context;
    protected MyAbstractListener listener;
    protected String userToBeDeleted;
    protected  JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    protected static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    protected static final String TAG_DELETION_FAILURE_CONNECTION_ERROR = "Connection Error"; 

    public MyAbstractTask(Context context, MyAbstractListener listener){
        this.context = context;
        this.listener = listener;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        ShowLoadingMessage.loading(context);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

   ...
}


public class DeleteUser extends MyAbstractTask<String> {
    private String userToBeDeleted;
    private static final String TAG_DELETION_SUCCESS = "Deletion Success";
    private static final String TAG_DELETION_FAILURE_ACCOUNT_NOT_DELETED = "Account Not Deleted";

    public DeleteUser(Context context, OnUserDeletionListener listener, String userToBeDeleted) {
       super(context, listener);
        this.userToBeDeleted = userToBeDeleted;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        int success;

            try {
                List<NameValuePair> deleteUserAccount = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                deleteUserAccount.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", userToBeDeleted));

                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(Configurationz.URLs.PHP_DELETE_USER_ACCOUNT, "POST", deleteUserAccount);

                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    return "Deletion Success";
                } else if (success == 2) {
                    return "Account Not Deleted";

                } else {
                    return "Connection Error";
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Connection Error";
            }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        ShowLoadingMessage.dismissDialog();
        if(listener != null) {
            if (result.contentEquals(TAG_DELETION_SUCCESS)) {
                listener.onUserDeletionSuccess();
            } else if(result.contentEquals(TAG_DELETION_FAILURE_ACCOUNT_NOT_DELETED)) {
                listener.onUserDeletionFailure(result);
            } else if(result.contentEquals(TAG_DELETION_FAILURE_CONNECTION_ERROR)) {    
                listener.onUserDeletionFailure(result); 
            }
        }
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```